# Error:Error 1 The name 'Children' does not exist in the current context

Tags: wpf

I am creating a application with WPF. In it I am implementing the `IScrollInfo` interface to get the visible region of the canvas. I am overriding the method `MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)` to get the viewport, but I get an error that I am not able to understand:

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
         {

            foreach (UIElement child in Children)
            {

                child.Measure(availableSize);
                resultSize.Width = Math.Max(resultSize.Width,
                child.DesiredSize.Width);
                resultSize.Height = Math.Max(resultSize.Height,
                        child.DesiredSize.Height);
                        extent.Width += child.DesiredSize.Width;
           }

            resultSize.Width = double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Width)? resultSize.Width : availableSize.Width;
            resultSize.Height = double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Height)? resultSize.Height : availableSize.Height;
            extent.Height = resultSize.Height;

           if ((_viewport != resultSize || _extent != extent) && ScrollOwner != null)

            {
                         _viewport = resultSize;
                         _extent = extent;

                         ScrollOwner.InvalidateScrollInfo();
            }

            return resultSize;
        }
```

What is children in it..

Answer (score 0):

As you use a Canvas, Children will be:

from MSDN [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx):

> Children       Gets a
>   UIElementCollection of child elements
>   of this Panel.  (Inherited from
>   Panel.)

All the "subitems" which are directly content of the Canvas.
In your case you have to move them now all according to the actual scroll state.

So if Children does not exist you wont extend Canvas...